# Panel Content not displaying correctly after migrating site to new server

Tags: panels, theming, migrations

This is how it looks like after I migrated the site. I compared the new panelizer and panels folders with a backup folder that I had  to see if there were discrepancies, but the folders had the same files. I also resaved the admin page as suggested in another post, but that didn't do it for me.

I am using D7 by the way.

[image]

Comment: Got any missing files among the HTTP requests? Check for 404s in firebug.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the dumb question, but what exactly do you mean by the HTTP requests? Is it an error or folder somewhere

Comment: When you're browser builds the admin page, it makes multiple requests over HTTP to the server to fetch resources, such as css files. If you look over that list, using whatever debugging tools your browser provides, you might be able to find out which file Panels is expecting to be there, but your browser fails to find.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a problem with the HTTP  requests. When I tried the site in Firefox the panels were back to normal . I would have never thought about the HTTP requests myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're browser builds the admin page, it makes multiple requests over HTTP to the server to fetch resources, such as css files. If you look over that list, using whatever debugging tools your browser provides, you might be able to find out which file Panels is expecting to be there, but your browser fails to find.